# Packer: Receiving ID not implemented for builder when using build.ID

Tags: vmware, packer

When trying to pass through build.ID to shell-local post processor the evaluate string in the post processor is **ERR_ID_NOT_IMPLEMENTED_BY_BUILDER** I am using vsphere-iso.

The docs mention

```
Here is the list of available build variables:

    ID: Represents the VM being provisioned. For example, in Amazon it is the instance ID; in DigitalOcean, it is the Droplet ID; in VMware, it is the VM name.
```

So I assumed it was supported with vsphere-iso?

Basically I am trying to passthrough the evaluated vm/template name through to a post powershell post processor.

Here is the post processor config:

```
  post-processor "shell-local" {
    environment_vars = [
      "VCENTER_USER=${var.vsphere_username}",
      "VCENTER_PASSWORD=${var.vsphere_password}",
      "VCENTER_SERVER=${var.vsphere_endpoint}",
      "TEMPLATE_NAME=${build.ID}",
      "TEMPLATE_UUID=${local.build_uuid}",
    ]
    env_var_format  = "$env:%s=\"%s\"; "
    execute_command = ["${var.common_post_processor_cli}.exe", "{{.Vars}} {{.Script}}"]
    script          = "scripts/windows/cleanup.ps1"
  }
```

Here is the post processor script

```
param(
    [string]
    $TemplateName = $env:TEMPLATE_NAME
)
Write-Host $TemplateName
```

Here is the result logged to the console

```
==> vsphere-iso.windows-server-standard-dexp (shell-local): Running local shell script: scripts/windows/cleanup.ps1
    vsphere-iso.windows-server-standard-dexp (shell-local): ERR_ID_NOT_IMPLEMENTED_BY_BUILDER
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code and full error message as the plugin source code does indicate the Packer SDK `generatedData` map is being populated.

Comment: I look through the various source code and this does not make any sense. This seems like an issue in the docs and/or an issue in the builder and/or Packer provisioner code. I would probably raise an issue on the builder first.